# 18.04 on Aero runs great until reboot. GTX 1070 GPU Issue?

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, gpu

SYSTEM: Gigabyte Aero 15x v8: i7-8750h (6-core), 32GB RAM, Dual SSD, GTX 1070 GPU
BIOS: "3D Graphic Acceleration" and "Security Device Support" (Trusted Computing) disabled and/or enabled.

My fresh and fully upgraded installation of Ubuntu runs fine until I reboot.  Then it goes like this:

1. Restart and see purple screen, then black forever (I've waited >hour).
2. Force restart & select Ubuntu in Grub
3. It starts verbose boot and usually freezes at:

`6.321643] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver`

but has also added lines such as:

`6.363908] random: crng init done
6.365077] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
6.384132] systemd-jounald[352]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1`

or

`6.147316] systemd-jounald[349: File /var/log/jounal/(numbersyadayada)/system.jounal corrupted or uncleanly shut down. renaming and replacing.
7.003647] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] No caching mode page found
7.004519] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through`

or

`tpm tpm0: A TPM error (370) ocurred get tpm pcr allocation`

Whatever it comes up with, it will sit at this point forever, AFAIK.  I've found 2 "solutions":

1. Kill it and let it sit for an hour or so, after which it will boot normally.
2. With "3D Graphic Acceleration" ENABLED in BIOS settings it will boot to the login page, but freeze indefinitely on login.  Not surprising since I had to disable it to get Ubuntu working, as per [this advice](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/8gz8wy/installing_ubuntu_mate_1804_on_the_gigabyte_aero/).

Seems like it's graphics-related.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After waiting an hour or more I was able to boot up and log in normally.  I then installed the Nvidia driver via 'Additional Drivers' in the 'Software & Updates' app.  It seems to be working normally now, with the bonus of having my dGPU working.